# Use of non-static member function for this Arduino library

Tags: c++, arduino, static, menu, member

In an Arduino project (C++) I use the [LiquidMenu](https://github.com/VaSe7u/LiquidMenu) library and I have difficulties to integrate this class in my own. The example provided are too simple for a real scenario.

Some code that does not compile:

main.cpp

```
const int rs = 3, en = 0, d4 = 4, d5 = 30, d6 = 12, d7 = 6;
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);

Menu menu(&lcd);

void setup() { }

void loop() { }
```

header

```
class Menu
{
public: 
    Menu(LiquidCrystal *lcd);        

private:
    int _myvar;

    LiquidCrystal *_lcd;
    LiquidMenu _menu;
    LiquidScreen _screenSetCC1;

    LiquidLine line1_setupCC1;
    LiquidLine line2_setupCC1;

    void editIntPlus();
};
```

cpp

```
Menu::Menu(LiquidCrystal *lcd) : _lcd(lcd), _menu(*_lcd),
    line1_setupCC1(0, 0, "Set CC #1"),
    line2_setupCC1(0, 1, _myvar)
{
    
    line2_setupCC1.attach_function(1, editIntPlus);

    _screenSetCC1.add_line(line1_setupCC1);
    _screenSetCC1.add_line(line2_setupCC1);
    _menu.add_screen(_screenSetCC1);
}

void Menu::editIntPlus()
{
    _myvar++;
}
```

first error is:

> error: invalid use of non-static member function 'void Menu::editIntPlus()'

But I cannot make that function static, otherwise I cannot access to `_myvar` anymore.
The [examples](https://github.com/VaSe7u/LiquidMenu/tree/master/examples/A_hello_menu) are not useful because they put everything outside any class and it's against any basic rule of programming.

Second question. In my menu I have dozens of `int` vars to set.
I really don't want to create a lot of functions to increase or decrease each single var!

How to retrieve, inside `editIntPlus()`, the current var being edited? The goal is to attach the same function to all the vars.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55094080/invalid-use-of-non-static-error-member-function-arduino) answer but:

1. I cannot declare `editIntPlus` as `friend`:

   friend:
   void editIntPlus();

leads to:

```
 include/menu.h:82:5: error: expected primary-expression before 'void'
     void editIntPlus();
     ^~~~
```

2. as said before, I don't want to make my function `static` otherwise I cannot access anymore to the class members

Comment: @JohnnyMopp corrected, to provide a minimal example I cut out a lot of other members and I forgot the `;` here.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, the line `82` is the last line of the header in the question. There are no other code involved. The offending "call" is reported in the cpp as well: `line2_setupCC1.attach_function(1, editIntPlus);`

Comment: I just noticed: `class Menu()` There shouldn't be parentheses there.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp corrected.

Comment: Assuming you have included the correct header for all those `Liquid*` classes, it looks ok. I tried to create an mre [here](https://godbolt.org/z/WM9hs6G69), but it is not exact since I don't have the headers for the liquid crystal stuff.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I think you are missing the point. He is trying to pass the non-static member function to `attach_function` which you can see in the repo expects a `void(*)()`. It doesn't have any additional parameter for a user data pointer either, so OP is probably out-of-luck and will have to resort to a static member function or a static class instance.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp as user1773522 pointed out you missed the setting of the callback - that is the problem I have. I don't want to believe the developer requires we have to use global variables and functions only!

Comment: @user17732522 if it's enough to add an additional parameter to fix this issue I can fork the library... would you mind to provide an example of how to use it?

Comment: I don't know about Arduino and absolutely nothing about the library, so this might not apply, but in C++-style you would replace the `_function` member with an array of `std::function<void()>` and make the argument of `attach_function` a template parameter. Then you can store any callable, e.g. a lambda capturing `this`. However `std::function` has significant overhead.

Comment: The C-style solution would be to change the function type to `void(*)(void*)` and add an argument to `attach_function` taking a `void*` (for which you pass `this`). This `void*` should then be stored in the class alongside `_function` and be always passed when the function is called. You can then use a lambda taking `this` by argument.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid both proposals are out of my current knowledge to be implemented easily. Perhaps the second one is more feasible for me... I'm going to try.

Comment: Here is a C example for the user data pointer approach, I guess you can find others on here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50874154/what-is-the-use-of-userdata-in-callback-register-function-in-c

Comment: Ah. I totally overlooked that you were passing it as a parameter. I guess if you plan on only having one lcd in your project, making everything static could work.

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestion of `user17732522` I forked the library making these changes:

LiquidMenu.h

```
void (*_function[MAX_FUNCTIONS])(void *); ///< Pointers to the functions
void (*_context[MAX_FUNCTIONS]); ///< Pointers to the contexts
```

LiquidLine.cpp

```
bool LiquidLine::attach_function(uint8_t number, void (*function)(void *), void* context) {

...
_context[number - 1] = context;

...
(*_function[number - 1])(_context[number - 1]);
```

and in my code (corrected after `user17732522` suggestion):

```
void editIntPlus(void *context);

line2_setupCC1.attach_function(1, [](void* context){ static_cast<Menu*>(context)->editIntPlus(context); }, this);
```

Comment: I was expecting I had to use the `context` variable in my `editIntPlus` function to access the real variables like `Menu *caller = static_cast<Menu *>(context); caller->_myvar;`. Instead it turns out I have to use just `_myvar`;

Comment: `(void (*)(void *)) &editIntPlus` is ill-formed. You cannot cast a pointer-to-member to a function-pointer in standard C++, nor can you form it from an unqualified name. It will be accepted by GCC only if the `-fpermissive` flag is used and that is a flag that should never be used IMO. It makes GCC allow all kind of stuff that is not standard-conform and may have very dubious behavior. Instead use a lambda: `line2_setupCC1.attach_function(1, [](void* context){ static_cast<Menu*>(context)->editIntPlus(); }, this);`

Comment: I'm going to study this topic because it's not easy to me to understand why that cast is not valid. And lambdas always scare me!